# Youtube Data API V3 unicodedecode utf8

Tags: python, json, utf-8, comments, youtube-data-api

Im following this [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) to retrieve comments of a youtube video using Youtube Data Api V3. I already have the "youtube-v3-discoverydocument.json", but when I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 187, in <module>
    youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
  File "test.py", line 73, in get_authenticated_service
    return build_from_document(doc, http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 140, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 305,      in build_from_docu
    service = json.loads(service)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 39: invalid continuation byte
```

Seems like it is in this part of the code:

```
with open("youtube-v3-discoverydocument.json", "r") as f:    
    doc = f.read()
return build_from_document(doc, http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
```

but I can't  figure out what is wrong, any advice?

Comment: python3 or python2 looks like a unicode issue. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0, thanks

Comment: Is `youtube-v3-discoverydocument.json` definitely utf-8 encoded?